# Are there any stats of Android version distribution by region?

Tags: android-versions

The [dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) shows global distribution, and I wonder if there's a way to find out the difference in Gingerbread distribution between say, India and Europe.

Comment: @9re, is there a requirement on what you can trust or from where you  would disregard the statistics?  There can be sites which might be having those statistics but with a questionable or absence of a method used to gather those statistics. Do we have an understanding that background of the site or the method used for statistics is not relevant?

Comment: @Firelord I think as long as the research process is somewhat explained, then it's okay.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not for those "ancient versions", but for Android 4.0+ you can find some stats in [Christina's Blog](http://www.christinacacioppo.com/blog/android-stats). Giving the example matching closest to your question:

[image: Android versions globally]

Answer (score 10):

I answered a similar [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129952/is-there-any-android-distribution-statistic-for-single-countries/129961#129961) some time ago. The best source I could find was this [site](https://deviceatlas.com/device-data/explorer/webusage-by-country/traffic/no-tablet/country/de/type/os_name_version), which bases its statistics on Internet traffic generated on the domain `.mobi`, managed by the domain registry [Afilias](http://www.afilias.info/), by mobile devices. The site gives access to statistics on the web usage by different OS versions (not only Android) by country. With the free access it is possible to select the country to look up, but with paid plans there are a lot of filters available to refine the queries. The process of comparing data can be lengthy, though, as you must look up country by country, there is no general overview.

Also note that: the statistics cannot be precise, as they are bounded to accesses on that particular domain name, but I think they can serve well for an overview.

Answer (score 2):

[StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/) have stats by region, showing for example, India's most popular is 6.0 Marshmallow compared with 7.0 Nougat in Europe.

## [India](http://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/india/):

[image: Marshmallow leads at 35%]

## [Europe](http://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/europe/):

[image: Nougat leads at 33%]

To get an idea how these might compare with the [dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), have a look at their [worldwide stats](http://gs.statcounter.com/android-version-market-share/mobile-tablet/worldwide).